# Does Eclipse have a variable visualizer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Visual Studio, there is a feature to add a [**custom visualizer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx) to the IDE. This allows you to write your own dialog showing the contents of complex objects at run-time (i.e. it might take a Person record and show the forename, surname and date of birth).

I can't find this feature in Eclipse/Java, but was wondering if it might be called something different?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: I don't suppose you mean the Variables view (usually found in the Debug perspective)?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, doesn't this just show the toString() value of an object? I'm after a way to cusomise this. In Visual Studio I've written a visualizer for the XmlNode, which shows the node in a nice programmer-friendly way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Feature is called Detail Formatter in Eclipse: [Details](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t16350.html)

Comment: ok, thanks. Seem that this is the closesst I'm going to get to it. I do like the visual studio visualizer, as it allows you to create your own dialog which can show a graphical respesentation of your objects. Maybe a plugin will become available for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a special dialog, but in general a custom implementation of .toString() do the trick.

Comment: If it was my own object, I could override the toString() method, but I want to write this for some built-in classes. (like the `node` class).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that you can get in Eclipse is [Variables View](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/variables/ref-variables_view.htm) and [Expressions](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/expressions/ref-expressions_view.htm).  view. You can also [Add a Watch Expression](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/expressions/ref-expressions_view.htm) in variables view to track any particular object.